# How to compute this "smooth max operator"?

Tags: numerical-methods, neural-networks, floating-point

I was seeking for an alternate way to activate each neuron of a neural network non-linearly. Eventually, I came up with the following binary operation:
$$
x \lor y = \log (\exp x + \exp y)
$$

With $-\infty$ being its identity element, along with associativity, this operator roughly works like $\max$. As such, I call this operator **smooth max**. To provide it some learnable parameters, use it as $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = b_0 \lor (w_1x_1+b_1) \lor \cdots \lor (w_nx_n+b_n)$.

I think this provides a good way of activating the neuron (in the next layer) they target, because of the following reasons:

- This operator is smooth.
- For $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x \lor y) = (1 + \exp(y-x))^{-1}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x \lor y) = (\exp(x-y) + 1)^{-1}$, it guarantees that at least one parameter will be effectively learned during backpropagation. That is, no worry of gradient vanishing problem.
- It provides some degree of non-linearity on its own, so it doesn't need a separate activation function.

For experimental purposes, I planned to actually use this operator for neural networks I've built. However, I also think there is a problem for this operator. Namely, directly invoking `exp` and `log` functions that most programming languages provide will be very prone to floating-point overflow, or floating-point error. So how should I compute this operator safely?

Comment: Some of the references here might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp

Comment: To everyone reading this post: This activation function suffers from exploding gradient problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume $x>y$. Then
$$
x \vee y = x + \log(1+\exp(y-x)).
$$
This should already fix the biggest problems.

Comment: note that when you do this, you should use a `log1p` implementation that which is the function `f(x) = log(1+x)`